# link response is 401 but it work sometime ago then works python

Tags: python, visual-studio

```
import requests
import json
import pandas as pd
new_url = 'https://www.nseindia.com/api/option-chain-indices?symbol=NIFTY'
headers = {'User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
response = requests.get(new_url, headers=headers)
dajs = json.loads(response.text).decode('utf-8')


JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)
```

Comment: 401 means unauthorized, If you don't have control over that api or can't authorize, there is nothing you can do with python here.

Comment: You _must_ check `response.status_code` before looking at `response.text`.